# Units of ipod/iphone gyroscope data?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod-touch

These things are not clear.
What are the units of 
1.Data given by (CMGyroData) basically x,y and z?

What is the minimum and maximum variation of one axis data(For eg, x axis)

Does this x data represent the rotation(or swing) around the x axis?

Answer (score 1):

The place to look is the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMGyroData_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

> `x`
>
> The X-axis rotation rate in radians per second. The sign follows the
>   right hand rule: If the right hand is wrapped around the X axis such
>   that the tip of the thumb points toward positive X, a positive
>   rotation is one toward the tips of the other four fingers.

etc.

Comment: Thank you! I have a small question for you! When i store gyro data to an array and try to log them using NSlog, it shows upto 6 decimal places? Can't i increase the number of decimal places it shows?